# Not Authorized to create vertexes in IBM Graph

Tags: ibm-graph

Tried to enter vertexes:

```
curl -X 'POST' -d '{"vertexLables": [{"name": "event"},{"name": "category"}]}' -H 'content-type: application/json' -H 'authorization: gds-token yyyy https://ibmgraph-alpha.ng.bluemix.net/zzzz/g/schema

{"code":"NotAuthorized","message":""}
```